# Java connect to CentralNIC EPP server

Tags: java, epp

I have this thread about flow connect to epp server [ssl socket communicatoin to an epp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013287/ssl-socket-communicatoin-to-an-epp-server).
My code:

```
Socket socket = sf.createSocket("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 700);
    String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n" +
            "<epp xmlns=\"urn:ietfaramsml:ns:epp-1.0\"\n" +
            "                xmlnssi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\n" +
            "                xsi:schemaLocation=\"urn:ietfaramsml:ns:epp-1.0 epp-1.0.xsd\">\n" +
            "<command xmlns=\"urn:ietfaramsml:ns:epp-1.0\">\n" +
            "  <login>\n" +
            "    <clID>user</clID>\n" +
            "    <pw>pass</pw>\n" +
            "    <options>\n" +
            "      <version>1.0</version>\n" +
            "      <lang>en</lang>\n" +
            "    </options>\n" +
            "    <svcs>\n" +
            "      <objURI>urn:ietfaramsml:nsomain-1.0</objURI>\n" +
            "      <objURI>urn:ietfaramsml:ns:contact-1.0</objURI>\n" +
            "      <objURI>urn:ietfaramsml:ns:host-1.0</objURI>\n" +
            "    </svcs>\n" +
            "  </login>\n" +
            "  <clTRID>ACCCCFFFFF</clTRID>\n" +
            "</command>\n" +
            "</epp>";
    socket.setSoTimeout(300000);

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new 
    OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()),true);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    writer.write(xml);
    writer.close();
    System.out.println("response 1:" + br.readLine());

    writer.println(xml);
    writer.close();
    System.out.println("response 2:" + br.readLine());
```

Response 1 return greeting message, and response 2 return null
How can i send login command to epp server right?

Comment: You close the writer, then try to ``write`` to it again. That's not going to work. Actually, I'd expect an Exception being thrown...

Comment: Besides @f1sh reply, note that you do not implement EPP properly. Each frame should be prefixed by the total length on 4 bytes. Have a look at section 4 of RFC3734.

Comment: Correct reference would now be instead RFC5734: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5734